# Cannot bind model in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to wpf and I just do a simple binding like this:

I have a class:

```
public class Test
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

and I set DataContext to it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Test a;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        a = new Test();
        a.x = 5;
        a.y = 6;
        DataContext = a;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.x);
        Console.WriteLine(a.y);
    }
}
```

In the XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding x}"></TextBox>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding y}"></TextBox>
<Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Show" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
```

then the textbox has no value, and when I press the button the value still the same.

I tried to bind like this in the tutorial:

```
DataContext = this;
```

in XAML:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Width}"></TextBox>
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Height}"></TextBox>
```

And it works, can someone pls explain to me what is wrong here ? 
thank you

Comment: You cannot bind to fields. Convert to property `public int x { get; set; }`

Comment: wow it works. thank you, do we have any reason why we cannot bind to fields ?

Comment: It's simply not valid binding source. Check [Binding Sources Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743643(v=vs.100).aspx#binding_sources) as to what is a valid binding source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments field is not a valid binding source. You need to convert it to property

```
public class Test
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
}
```

For the full list of valid binding sources check [Binding Sources Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743643(v=vs.100).aspx#binding_sources) link but in short

> You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object

Comment: And just as a suggestion, name your properties with an upper case letter (`public int X {get; set;}`). You might want to implement a manual backing field `private int x` later, for example when you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.